# How to correctly urlencode a string in Swift to be decoded uses PHP urldecode?

Tags: php, swift, urlencode, urldecode

I would like to send some URL encoded data from a Swift app to a PHP API where the data is decoded again.

While this works fine most of the time, I know became aware that PHP urldecode handles the + sign differently than the Swift addingPercentEncoding and decodes the + to a space.

How can this be avoided?

```
// Swift
let data = "some+test"
let encodedData = data.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)  // some+test
sendToMyServer(encodedData)

// PHP
$encodedData = $receivedData;             // some+text
$decodedData = urldecode($encodedData);   // some text
```

It seems that Swift does not consider the + sign in any of its build in (inverted) char sets:

```
URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet  "#%<>[\]^`{|}
URLHostAllowedCharacterSet      "#%/<>?@\^`{|}
URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet  "#%/:<>?@[\]^`{|}
URLPathAllowedCharacterSet      "#%;<>?[\]^`{|}
URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet     "#%<>[\]^`{|}
URLUserAllowedCharacterSet      "#%/:<>?@[\]^`
```

Is there a reason why PHP handles the + sign in this way?

What is the "correct" way to solve this? I assume I could simple define a custom char set which includes the + sign, but I am not sure if this might lead to other unexpected side effects. Is this safe or are there other differences in PHP urldecode which needs to be considered?

Comment: Maybe a hint there: `This differs from the » RFC 3986 encoding (see rawurlencode()) in that for historical reasons, spaces are encoded as plus (+) signs.` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php using different "reference rules" (RFC)

Comment: So check `$decodedData = rawurldecode($encodedData);`?

Comment: RFC 3986 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

Answer (score 1):

For the reason:

Doc of [`CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset/1780202-urlhostallowed):

> Returns the character set for characters allowed in a host URL subcomponent.

If we then go to implicitly linked doc of [`URLComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents/)

> This structure parses and constructs URLs according to RFC 3986. Its behavior differs subtly from that of the URL structure, which conforms to older RFCs. However, you can easily obtain a URL value based on the contents of a URLComponents value or vice versa.

The doc of PhP [`urldecode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) says:

> Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character.

The `urlencode` says:

> This differs from the » RFC 3986 encoding (see rawurlencode()) in that for historical reasons, spaces are encoded as plus (+) signs.

So iOS uses the `RFC 3986` and PhP doesn't.

Solution:

Use the same encoding/decoding, by changing it on iOS or in the server.

For the server changes:

To use the same as iOS on the server side, use [`rawurldecode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) (or [`rawurlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) if needed), as it says:

> rawurldecode() does not decode plus symbols ('+') into spaces. urldecode() does.

and

> rawurlencode — URL-encode according to RFC 3986

For the iOS changes:

See [Sajjad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75956542/1801544)